# Get Vuejs Store variable by String Value

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get a vuejs store variable like this :

`` const pathFile = `#pathFile_${this.devisDTO.code_produit}`;
const pathApp = this.$store.state.parameters.urls.${pathFile}; ``

So in the second line `${pathFile}` is not interpreted in that way. Please could you help on how to write this ?

Comment: try `this.$store.state.parameters.urls[pathFile]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript `${string_name}` is used inside template strings (1). If you want to access the value of a dictionary based on a string's content you should use the square brackets syntax. In your case

```
this.$store.state.url[path_file]
```

On a side note I suggest you to use store getters to access variables.

(1): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

pathFile is a normal variable. Remove the brackets from it.

```
const pathFile = `#pathFile_${this.devisDTO.code_produit}`;
const pathApp = this.$store.state.parameters.urls.pathFile;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify your code remove brackets from parameters.urls.${pathFile} to .urls.pathFile;

here is code..

```
const pathFile = `#pathFile_${this.devisDTO.code_produit}`;
const pathApp = this.$store.state.parameters.urls.pathFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid javascript. I am guessing you meant to write the following:

```
const pathFile = `#pathFile_${this.devisDTO.code_produit}`;
const pathApp = this.$store.state.parameters.urls[pathFile];
```